# Re-prompt until correct data format input

Tags: java, while-loop

I wrote this code for my Java course project that gets the phone number in the 1800LETTERS and outputs the number as 1-800-538-8377. The thing that I am struggling with is that I want to keep prompting until the user inputs the phone number in the correct format (1800LETTERS).
I know that I should use a while loop but I don't know where to plug it. Also the program should not run until the user inputs the correct format, otherwise, the code throws up some exceptions. I think if I use the while loop in correct place, the user should not be able to enter incorrect input.
I appreciate your help.
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PhoneNumberConverter {

    public static boolean isValidPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        if (phoneNumber.matches("\\d{4}\\w{7}"))
            return true;
        else if (phoneNumber.matches("\\d{1}\\d{3}\\w{7}"))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    
    public static int translatePhoneNumber (String phoneNumber, int firstIndex, int lastIndex) {
    
        int chartoNumber = 'A';
        int currentIndex;   
        if (firstIndex == 0) {
            for (currentIndex = firstIndex; currentIndex < lastIndex; currentIndex++) {
                chartoNumber =  phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex);
                char number = (char) chartoNumber;
                System.out.print(number);
            }   
        } 
        else if (firstIndex == 1) {
            for (currentIndex = firstIndex; currentIndex < lastIndex; currentIndex++) {
                chartoNumber =  phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex);
                char number = (char) chartoNumber;
                System.out.print(number);
            }   
        } 
        else {
            for (currentIndex = firstIndex; currentIndex < lastIndex; currentIndex++) {
                if (phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'A' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'B' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'C' )
                    chartoNumber = 2;
                else if (phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'D' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'E' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'F' )
                    chartoNumber = 3;
                else if (phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'G' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'H' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'I' )
                    chartoNumber = 4;
                else if (phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'J' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'K' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'L' )
                    chartoNumber = 5;
                else if (phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'M' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'N' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'O' )
                    chartoNumber = 6;
                else if (phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'P' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'Q' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'R' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'S' )
                    chartoNumber = 7;
                else if (phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'T' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'U' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'V' )
                    chartoNumber = 8;
                else if (phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'W' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'X' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'Y' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'Z' )
                    chartoNumber = 9;
                else
                    chartoNumber =  phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex);
                
                    System.out.print(chartoNumber);     
                }
        }
        return chartoNumber;    
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println("Enter a phone number to convert:");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String enteredNumber = input.next();
        String phoneNumber = enteredNumber.toUpperCase();
        
        boolean validationResult = isValidPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
        System.out.println(validationResult);
        input.close();
        
        translatePhoneNumber (phoneNumber, 0, 1);
        System.out.print("-");
        
        translatePhoneNumber (phoneNumber, 1, 4);
        System.out.print("-");
        
        translatePhoneNumber (phoneNumber, 4, 7);
        System.out.print("-");
        
        translatePhoneNumber (phoneNumber, 7, 11);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to use a while loop here.

You can create a function to get the input, validate it and return it if's valid. If it's not valid, throw an exception and in the exception handling, invoke the function again.

```
    public string getInput() {
    try{
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String enteredNumber = input.next();
        if(!isValidPhoneNumber(enteredNumber)
           throw new InputMismatchException("Wrong Format");
        else
           return enteredNumber;
    } catch (InputMismatchException ex){
       return getInput();
    }
}
```

Then call getInput where your original `String enteredNumber = input.next();` was

so

```
String enteredNumber = getInput()
```

If the user gets the wrong input, the function will be called until the right input is provided.

Comment: Could you clarify where in my code your edit should be inserted? I don't seem to plug it into the right location.

Comment: The method definition itself will go wherever you want. Put it at the end of your code if you will. The invocation of the method will replace the line where you assigned enteredNumber to be equal to the user input. In YOUR code you have the line String enteredNumber = input.next(). Replace that with String enteredNumber = getInput();

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PhoneNumberConverter {

    public static boolean isValidPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        if (phoneNumber.matches("\\d{4}\\w{7}"))
            return true;
        else if (phoneNumber.matches("\\d{1}\\d{3}\\w{7}"))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public static int translatePhoneNumber (String phoneNumber, int firstIndex, int lastIndex) {

        int chartoNumber = 'A';
        int currentIndex;
        if (firstIndex == 0) {
            for (currentIndex = firstIndex; currentIndex < lastIndex; currentIndex++) {
                chartoNumber =  phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex);
                char number = (char) chartoNumber;
                System.out.print(number);
            }
        }
        else if (firstIndex == 1) {
            for (currentIndex = firstIndex; currentIndex < lastIndex; currentIndex++) {
                chartoNumber =  phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex);
                char number = (char) chartoNumber;
                System.out.print(number);
            }
        }
        else {
            for (currentIndex = firstIndex; currentIndex < lastIndex; currentIndex++) {
                if (phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'A' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'B' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'C' )
                    chartoNumber = 2;
                else if (phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'D' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'E' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'F' )
                    chartoNumber = 3;
                else if (phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'G' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'H' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'I' )
                    chartoNumber = 4;
                else if (phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'J' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'K' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'L' )
                    chartoNumber = 5;
                else if (phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'M' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'N' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'O' )
                    chartoNumber = 6;
                else if (phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'P' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'Q' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'R' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'S' )
                    chartoNumber = 7;
                else if (phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'T' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'U' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'V' )
                    chartoNumber = 8;
                else if (phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'W' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'X' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'Y' || phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex) == 'Z' )
                    chartoNumber = 9;
                else
                    chartoNumber =  phoneNumber.charAt(currentIndex);

                System.out.print(chartoNumber);
            }
        }
        return chartoNumber;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean validationResult=false;
        do {
            try{
                System.out.println("Enter a phone number to convert:");
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                String enteredNumber = input.next();
                String phoneNumber = enteredNumber.toUpperCase();

                validationResult = isValidPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
                if(validationResult==false){
                    System.out.println("Entered phone number is incorrect.");
                }
                System.out.println(validationResult);
                input.close();

                translatePhoneNumber(phoneNumber, 0, 1);
                System.out.print("-");

                translatePhoneNumber(phoneNumber, 1, 4);
                System.out.print("-");

                translatePhoneNumber(phoneNumber, 4, 7);
                System.out.print("-");

                translatePhoneNumber(phoneNumber, 7, 11);
                System.out.println();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }while(validationResult==false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have used do-while loop which is an exit control loop . We have to run the code at least for once in that case do-while loop is preferable.Hope it helped :)

Comment: The code still does not re-prompt if the user inputs the wrong format.

Comment: Hope it helps now.